# Are IRIs valid as HTML attribute values?

Tags: html, utf-8, uri, urlencode

Is it valid HTML to use IRIs containing non-ASCII characters as attribute values (e.g. for `href` attributes) instead of URIs? Are there any differences among the HTML flavors (HTML and XHTML, 4 and 5)? At least [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-16) seems to imply that it isn't.

I realize that it would probably be safer (regarding older and IRI-unaware software) to use percent encoding, but I'm looking for a definitive answer with regards to the standard.

So far, I've done some tests with the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/), and unescaped unicode characters in URIs don't trigger any warnings or errors with HTML 4/5 and XHTML 4/5 doctypes (but of course the absence of error messages doesn't imply the absence of errors).

At least chrome also supports raw UTF-8 IRIs, but percent-escapes them before firing an HTTP request. Also, my web server (lighttpd) seems to support UTF-8 characters in their percent-encoded as well as in unencoded form in an HTTP request.

Comment: Beware that [Section 1.2 of RFC 3987](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3987#section-1.2) mentions that HTTP as defined by [RFC 2616](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616) does **NOT** support IRIs so handling them is outside of the standard. You (or your browser, or someone) need to map a given IRI to a URI first before trying to retrieve the referenced resource.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unicode characters in URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML 4.01 is straightforward enough. Different attributes have different rules as to what they can contain, but if we're dealing with the href attribute on an `<a>` element, then the [HTML 4 spec, section B.2.1 Non-ASCII characters in URI attribute values](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#non-ascii-chars) says:

> ... the following href value is illegal:
>
> `<A href="http://foo.org/Håkon">...</A>`

HTML5 is different. It says [IRIs are valid providing they comply with some additional conditions.](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/infrastructure.html#valid-url)

> A URL is a valid URL if at least one of the following conditions
>   holds:
>
> - The URL is a valid URI reference [RFC3986].
> - The URL is a valid IRI reference and it has no query component. [RFC3987]
> - The URL is a valid IRI reference and its query component contains no unescaped non-ASCII characters. [RFC3987]
> - The URL is a valid IRI reference and the character encoding of the URL's Document is UTF-8 or a UTF-16 encoding. [RFC3987]

XHTML 1.x follows the same rules as HTML 4.01.

XHTML5 is the same as HTML5.

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt, read the official HTML specs for definitive answers.

HTML 4 does not support IRIs at all.  They must be encoded as URIs per [RFC 3987 Section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987#section-3.1), or encode non-ASCII URI data as UTF-8 with percent encoding per [HTML4 Section B.2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#non-ascii-chars)

HTML 5 supports both URIs and IRIs in all places where URLs are allowed, per [HTML5 Section 2.6](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/infrastructure.html#urls).